# How to perform normalization on logical ERD?

Tags: normalization, database-normalization, erd

Below are my conceptual & logical ERD.
My question is how to find the unnormalized form? For my understanding normalisation should be performed on a logical design phase, right? But everything looks like having been normalised. I am so confused.

**Conceptual ERD:**

[image]

**Logical ERD:**

[image]

Comment: Neither of your diagrams are ERDs (I use that term only for diagrams that use Chen's notation) and your logical diagram has nothing to do with logical modeling, since it doesn't specify functional dependencies. Normalization is based on understanding and manipulating functional dependencies. Look into relational diagrams or just list your functional dependencies in text. Also, it doesn't make sense to try to "find the unnormalized form". Unnormalized isn't a relational form, it's anything that isn't a relation.

Comment: Thanks for reply..But what i had learned are, normally we will have a table with some attributes combined from different tables and some records (Unnormalized form). From the table we will find out the F.D then we will normalise it. Since i don't have the table now, so these are the only details i got..But everything look like arranged..thanks again..hope u will understand my english

Comment: You don't need an unnormalized table before finding FDs. You can analyze each of your current tables. For example, in `Product_Warranty`, does `ProSN -> WarrID`? Does `WarrID -> ProSN`? How about `WarrID -> WarrStatus`, `WarrID -> SuppID` and `WarrID -> CusID`? After you've written down all the dependencies that hold among all your fields, and ensure that your tables are in 1NF at least, you will have a logical data model.

Comment: this enlighten me..At first, i thought i need to combine entities with relationship because this make more sense..thanks again